# how to transform a span with link as classname to an <a href=""> Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I am getting an HTML output from an expression from angularjs. In this angularjs expression {{html}}, I get some HTML code blocks like this.

```
<p>sometext ....<span class="externallink::https://www.siv.archives-nationales.culture.gouv.fr/siv/IR/FRAN_IR_054007 foreground-blue underline-1  ">Online-Findbuch</span>...some text</p>
```

Now I need to transform it to something I can work with. A simple working link. For example.

```
<p>some text ....<a class="foreground-blue underline-1" href="https://www.siv.archives-nationales.culture.gouv.fr/siv/IR/FRAN_IR_054007">Online-Findbuch</a>...some text </p>
```

So as you can see, there are several problems to solve. How to read and transform the span with the class "externallink::" to an Link with the added address. Leave the class names without the "externallink::" as a class name and transform the "Online-Findbuch" span name to a link name.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What. Your question is totally unclear : please read [ask], and provide a [mcve] of your issue showing the original code, the expected result, and what you have currently tried to reach that expected result.

Comment: How is that link working with that malformed url? There's 2 spaces within the url  and multiple spaces at the end of url.

Comment: I've edited my question. Sorry it was a horrible description.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is really unclear, trying whatever can be understood from that:

There can be many methods to do, this is one using jQuery

```
var span = $('<span class="externallink::https://www.siv.archives- 
nationales.culture.gouv.fr/siv/IR/FRAN_IR_054007 foreground-blue underline-1  
">Online-Findbuch</span>')

var spanClass = span[0].classList[0];

var aHref = spanClass.replace('externallink::', '');

var a = $("<a>");

a.attr('href', aHref);
```